# How do you get get absent rows from a SQL table?

Tags: sql, missing-data, insertion

I am not sure if I had asked the question correctly in title, but here the proper scenario.

Suppose I have SQL table in which rows are inserted everyday. In these rows there is one column which has one set of values. That means in this column, let's call it Source_system, we receive 20 values each day. Same distinct values everyday. Now is there any way I can get the name of the source system which is not inserted for that day?

EDIT: Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Show us table definitions, some sample data, and the wanted result.

Comment: _Now is there any way I can get the name of the source system which is not inserted for that day?_ Yes.  Using an outer join and a list of all the systems.  Example assuming yourTableName has a complete set of values: `Select ST.InsertedDay, B.Source_System from (Select Distinct source_System from yourTableName) B LEFT JOIN yourTableName  ST on B.Source_System = ST.Source_System WHERE ST.Source_System is null`

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario. Suppose there is one table which maintains the attendance record of students. It has 3 columns, student_name, date and attendance(Y/N). Now the row is filled for student only if student came on that day, or else nothing would be inserted in this table. So basically I want to fetch the name of the students who didn't show up on a specific date (whose rows are not inserted on that day) I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depending on the way your data is formatted. If the Source_system entries that are not inserted are null, a simple `Where` statement can be used to find what's blank and get the name of the rest of the columns

```
Select *
From Table_name
Where Source_system is null
```

Since your 20 distinct values are known, if you have these in a table, you can also `Outer Join` the tables and find the rows where Source_system doesn't match the entries in the table of distinct values

```
Select Date_inserted_into_db, Source_system
From Table_name T1
Full Outer Join Table_of_distinct_values T2 on T1.Source_system = T2.Source_system
Where Source_system is null
```

Comment: Well if say only data from 19 source systems is loaded, then only 19 values will be inserted in this table. Nothing else, not even null. In other words if data from this missing source system hasn't been loaded, the entry wouldn't be there in Source_system column at all.